# silverlight spreadsheetgear WorkbookView read only mode

Tags: silverlight, spreadsheetgear

Is there a way to switch **WorkBookView** in read only mode?

So the user will not be allowed to edit cells, paste to cells, use AutoFill feature, change width/height of columns/row, but still be able to switch between sheets and copy text from cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option might be to use worksheet protection.  This would involve ensuring IRange.[Locked](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~Locked.html) is set to true for all the cells you don't want modifiable (all cells in a worksheet have `Locked` set to true by default) and then enforcing worksheet protection via either:

- IWorksheet.[ProtectContents](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IWorksheet~ProtectContents.html)
- IWorksheet.[Protect](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.7.0/#SpreadsheetGear2012.Core~SpreadsheetGear.IWorksheet~Protect.html)(*password*)

Users would then be restricted from editing, pasting into or otherwise altering cell contents, changing the width/height of row/column headers...etc.  The user could still navigate to other sheets or copy cell contents with worksheet protection enabled.

Comment: Protection looks good, but what about message boxes. Is this a way to not showing it at all?